# No VST rendering on Tracktion T7 Waveform 11 free

Tags: midi, software, daw, vst, windows-10

I'm using LABS VST instrument plugin on a MIDI track in Tracktion T7 Waveform 11 free. I'm working on Windows 10, on a ACER Aspire V Nitro Black Edition Laptop, native soundcard.
I can hear the VST instruments while editing, but they are not rendered when exporting. It happens on VST, there's no problem when using native 4OSC plugins.

After rendering the VST midi track (which results in an empty audio file), I get this message track: "This track contains MIDI-generating clips which may be inaudible as it doesn't output to a MIDI device or a plugin synthesiser". Then. the VST instruments in the track stop being audible while editing.

[image: Midi inaudible Message]

**Track destination**

I tried the different track destination options:

- Default audio
- Default MIDI output
- Output 1+2
- Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth

The situation remained the same.

[image]

**Plugin Synth**
I don't understand how to output the track to a plugin synthesiser. I'll thank info on that subject.

**Audio Device Type**
On Configuration/Audio devices, I tried changing the Audio Device Type, hoping I was experiencing [this situation](https://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=526791). But this didn't work. I can choose:

- Windows audio
- Windows audio (exclusive mode)
- DirectSound
- ASIO

I can only choose as output:
Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)SST))

*If I choose ASIO, there's no output to be selected.*

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because software manufacturer support question.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is very late but just in case; I had this same problem and was able to solve it by updating my output setting for the whole program (found within the main setting), for some reason it was set to "none".

Hope this helps even if six months late lol.